# Accessing files in the same folder from two applications

Tags: c#

I have this system with two applications A and B. There are multiple instances of B running. the application A and B do not communicate to each other directly. They share the same folder.

The application A will copy a file to a folder, where the instances of application B will copy that file to its own temporary folder and start to process. The problem here is that: there are a number of instances of application B. It can happen that not all the instances of application B have not copied the file to its own temporary folder and application A is about copying a new file to overwrite the previous one.

The applications A and B are written in C#. As application A does not have the knowledge how many instances of B running therefore I am having a problem of preventing A to start the copy process while there are still other instances of B need to copy the file to its temporary folder.

Comment: So, what is the criteria for instances of app B. If any no. of instances can be created, how to determine its final instance to kickoff app A.

Comment: applications A and B are separately. they dont communication directly to each other. Currently, we dont have a limit of no. of instances of B

Comment: Is there a particular reason your copying a file into the folder and over writing it?  Could you not check if the file exist prior to and enter a sleep state till its able to be processed by app b, then app A copy it over? Does app b care about the names of these files where it could just blindly process any file entered into the folder?

Comment: In this case, you can check if instance of B completed its task by maintaining state somewhere but how would you know if app B instances won't be created anymore.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change what A and/or B do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` shouldn't overwrite any previous files it produced - it has no idea if there are more instances of `B` that want to work on that file. Instead, `A` needs to create new files in the output folder as it produces output - one good approach is to use a timestamp as part of the filename so that multiple files can be ordered by date easily (file creation dates could also be used for that purpose).

Instances of `B` should use a shared file (MySql database, etc.) that keeps track of instances of `B` using a given file. Access to this shared file should be synchronized using a mutex/semaphore (if access is not already synchronized). When all `B` instances are done with a file, the last one can delete the input file that's not needed anymore. How this could be done would depend on what kind of communication is possible among instances of `B`.

Keep in mind, this is just one idea - this is a relatively complicated problem and there are several ways to solve it.